# User allocation microservice

Tags: .net, database, microservices

We have an automation framework (.NET) that is used to run on different environments. For each environment there are some specific test users that are used. Can anyone give some opinion on what is the correct way to approach this and potential problems that might occur? (THANKS!)

My idea is to have a database with the user credentials for each environment and also a microservice that locks and releases a specific user for that environment:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that the better way to do that is to have different instances for each environment, if this is not possible, perhaps have different databases in the same instance so each environment will be totally isolated from the other environments.

The selection of the database could be done through environment variables